# Driver interdependence

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, dependencies

I recently tried to install the Ratoc U2SCX driver into Windows 10, in XP compatibility mode (the final purpose was to connect an older SCSI scanner). However, the driver seems to crash W10. I removed what I could but one part of the driver remained and when plugging in my USB CD drive, I got a BSOD (that clearly mentioned u2scxfwu64.sys as the culprit).

After deactivating this driver by using Autoruns, I found that the external CD rom did not crash Windows anymore, but was also not working. See the screenshot : [Device manager USB Mass Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2TRM.png) The problem is, as shown on that screenshot, that somehow, even if it should not be used, the Ratoc driver must have replaced the default Windows USB mass storage driver by its own, which now requires that u2scxfwu64.sys file.

How would you remove the dependency of the USB mass storage driver to that Ratoc one? I tried the uninstalling function of the device manager, but at the next reboot the same driver was used.

Comment: What about just deleting that file? Create a full system backup then just delete that file plus check registry for occurrences. Additionally performing `sfc /scannow` may be a good idea.

Comment: When I remove the driver file (just renaming to something different), I still cannot access my USB mass storage devices. Each of them shows "Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

Object Name not found."